# document.getElementsByClassName exact match to class

Tags: javascript

There are two similar classes - 'item' and 'item one'

When I use `document.getElementsByClassName('item')` it returns all elements that match both classes above.

How I can get elements with 'item' class only?

Comment: The last one is'nt a similar class, it's the exact same class, ***and*** the class `one`, space seperation means two different classes !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The classname `item one` means the element has class `item` and class `one`.

So, when you do `document.getElementsByClassName('item')`, it returns that element too.

You should do something like this to select the elements with only the class `item`:

```
e = document.getElementsByClassName('item');
for(var i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
    // Only if there is only single class
    if(e[i].className == 'item') {
        // Do something with the element e[i]
        alert(e[i].className);
    }
}
```

This will check that the elements have only class `item`.

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2Yzmr/)

Comment: ok, I got it. But how I can get elements which belong to class 'item' and not class 'one'?

Comment: (e[i].className!="item one") works, but not your condition. I think because in my case first class is 'item '

Comment: @Marat Can you share your HTML?

Answer (score 5):

```
document.querySelectorAll('.item:not(.one)');
```

(see [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll))

The other way is to loop over the what `document.getElementsByClassName('item')` returns, and check if the `one` class is present (or not):

```
if(element.classList.contains('one')){
  ...
}
```

Comment: No jquery specified by OP.

Comment: Right, but it is not recommended. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11503534/jquery-vs-document-queryselectorall

Comment: That answer details the advantages of jQuery over using `querySelectorAll`. If you start talking about compatibility, then you should know that `getElementsByClassName` is also inconsistent across browsers. It's up to the OP to support older browsers, if (s)he wants to do so

Answer (score 2):

If you have jQuery, it can be done using the [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) syntax like this: `$('[class="item"]')`.

If you insist on using `document.getElementsByClassName`, see the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to make your own function for exact matches, because spaces in a class means it has multiple classes. Something like:

```
function GetElementsByExactClassName(someclass) {
  var i, length, elementlist, data = [];

  // Get the list from the browser
  elementlist = document.getElementsByClassName(someclass);
  if (!elementlist || !(length = elementlist.length))
    return [];

  // Limit by elements with that specific class name only
  for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if (elementlist[i].className == someclass)
      data.push(elementlist[i]);
  }

  // Return the result
  return data;
} // GetElementsByExactClassName
```

Comment: if the className is specified as `<elem class="  test  " />` this won't include it, even though it only has the one class. Don't make your test be strict string equality. Otherwise, good answer +1

Comment: In that case, it is still correct because I was assuming he wanted the test to be EXACTLY what was in the class field. He didn't specify whether or not that was the requirement. But yeah, I can see that as well...

Comment: well it does exactly match the class...spaces are irrelevant in the `class` attribute. He didn't say exactly match the class attribute, because that's pointless

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter the matched set to be only those with class `test`:

```
var elems = Array.filter( document.getElementsByClassName('test'), function(el){
    return !!el.className.match(/\s*test\s*/);
});
```

Or only those with `test` but not `one`:

```
var elems = Array.filter( document.getElementsByClassName('test'), function(el){
    return el.className.indexOf('one') < 0;
});
```

(`Array.filter` may work differently depending on your browser, and is not available in older browsers.) For best browser compatibility, [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/) would be excellent for this: `$('.test:not(.one)')`