# Simple JavaScript Selector

Tags: javascript

Using pure JavaScript without any library like jQuery, how could I detect if a variable holds a DOM Class or ID?

For example if I pass into a function a value that could be...

```
var mySelector = ".class-name";
```

or

```
var mySelector = "#id-name";
```

Then based on if `mySelector` holds a Class or ID I would run

```
document.getElementsByClassName
```

or

```
document.getElementsById
```

What would be the best way to do this without the use of a library like jQuery or another library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelector) or [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll), instead. Both of those can find elements by ID or class (as well as other selectors). querySelector will return 1 element, querySelectorAll will return all elements.

```
var mySelector = ".class-name", // "#id-name" will also work fine.
elements = document.querySelectorAll(mySelector);
```

Note that this doesn't work in IE < 8 (see http://caniuse.com/#search=querySelectorAll). A polyfill would be the best way to handle it to add IE7 support.

Comment: While this is a great solution, it is probably worth noting that this doesn't work on IE < 8... But hopefully we don't worry about that any more (or at least not for much longer). :)

Comment: Also, browser native query selector implementations are far faster than JavaScript string manipulation.

Comment: @Steve, `querySelectorAll` has better browser support than `getElementsByClassName`. [Clicky](http://caniuse.com/queryselector)

Comment: @Steve Good point. I've updated my answer to point this out. If IE7 support is required, a polyfill would be the recommended approach.

Comment: True, but if two elements have the same `id` (which they **shouldn't**), `querySelectorAll` will return both

Comment: @Steve, It's IE8 that you're missing.  8 supports querySelectorAll, but not getElementsByClassName

Comment: This is clearly debatable but I choose this answer as the best lightweight solution for my current need.  Obviously for anything important I would use jQuery or Sizzle but I really like this newer JS method

Comment: @jasondavis, You might peek at [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11503576/897559) for some more information.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this simple `if/else` statement to differentiate. This would also allow you to run other code based on whether it's a class or an ID you are referencing.

```
var mySelector = ".class-name";

if(mySelector.charAt(0) == ".")
{
    document.getElementsByClassName(mySelector.substring(1));
}
else if(mySelector.charAt(0) == "#")
{
    document.getElementsById(mySelector.substring(1));
}
```

Comment: Why not `mySelector.charAt(0)`?

Comment: @Ian, yes that would also work. Really just comes down personal preference.

Comment: True, but `charAt` is far faster (although probably unnoticeable), and semantically makes more sense. Still, personal preference is the factor

Comment: Note that getElementsByClassName doesn't work in IE8 and below. http://caniuse.com/#search=getElementsByClassName

Comment: @Ian Might as well change it to `charAt`. It does entail a few less characters of code.

Comment: @Ian, not that unnoticeable  [http://jsperf.com/sunsean-substr-charat](http://jsperf.com/sunsean-substr-charat)

Comment: @Travis True (and I've looked at http://jsperf.com/substr-or-charat ) but what I meant by "unnoticeable" was that I doubt you'll actually notice that difference when the code is running...unless the code is executed rapidly or in a loop

Answer (score 1):

The first way I think is check a first symbol of stroke.
Something like:

```
var $ = function( string ) {
  var result;
  switch (string.substr(0,1)) {
    case '.': result = document.getElementsByClassName(string); break;
    case '#': result = document.getElementById(string); break;
    default: result = document.getElementsByTagName(string); break;
  }
  return result;
}
var mySelector = ".class-name";
console.log( $(mySelector) );
```

Answer (score 1):

**Just because you only want a selector and not the entire jQuery library**, doesn't mean you have to roll your own own.  jQuery uses the Sizzle selector engine, and you could just as easily use it yourself without the overhead of full jQuery:

http://sizzlejs.com/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an advanced user, but some time ago I created this little script:

https://gist.github.com/caiotarifa/cc7d486292f39157d763

```js
var __;

__ = function(selector, filter) {
  'use strict';

  var response;

  function filtering(selectors, filter) {
    switch (filter) {
      case "first":
        return selectors[0];
        break;
      case "last":
        return selectors[selectors.length - 1];
        break;
      default:
        return selectors[filter];
        break;
    }
  }

  selector = selector.trim();
  if (typeof filter === "string") { filter = filter.trim(); }

  if (selector.indexOf(' ') < 0 && selector.indexOf('.', 1) < 0 && selector.indexOf('#', 1) < 0) {
    switch (selector.substr(0, 1)) {
      case '.':
        response = document.getElementsByClassName(selector.substr(1));
        if (response.length === 1) { filter = "first"; }
        if (typeof filter !== "undefined") { response = filtering(response, filter) }
        break;
      case '#':
        response = document.getElementById(selector.substr(1));
        break;
      default:
        response = document.getElementsByTagName(selector);
        if (response.length === 1) { filter = "first"; }
        if (typeof filter !== "undefined") { response = filtering(response, filter) }
        break;
    }
  } else {
    if (typeof filter !== "undefined") {
      switch (filter) {
        case "first":
          response = document.querySelector(selector);
          break;
        case "last":
          response = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
          response = response[response.length - 1];
          break;
        default:
          response = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
          response = response[filter];
          break;
      }
    } else {
      response = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
      if (response.length === 1) { response = response[0]; }
      else if (response.length < 1) { response = false; }
    }
  }

  return response;
};
```

It's simple to use it:

```
__("div")
```

Or passing some filter like:

```
__("div", "first")
```

I didn't make a benchmark test with it. I hope it can help you.