# How to use javascript selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a way in javascript to select a selector within another selector like in jQuery:

```
$("section h1").html();
```

Comment: document.querySelectorAll() ?

Comment: What does *select a selector within another selector* mean, exactly?

Comment: "to select a selector within another selector like in jQuery:" that's a tongue twister.

Comment: I think he means a non-jQuery way to select a `<h1>` within a `<section>`.

Comment: You might want something like var selecttor = $("section h1").html().find('selector'); $(selector).blablabla :)

Comment: Use childNodes/parentNode

Answer (score 3):

[jQuery](http://jquery.com/) actually uses [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) when available. Thing is, on your own, you'll never be able to emulate all the goodies that jQuery provides (e.g., `filter()`, `find()`, `children()`, `parent()`, `map()`, `not()` and the ability to use pseudo-classes).

This would be enough to grab the h1 element in section:

```
var e = document.querySelector("section h1");
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qd6b5/).

Read on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/11503576/2612112.

Answer (score 1):

Closest you'll find is probably `document.querySelector` or `document.querySelectorAll`. Should be careful though, as support is limited to modern browsers.

Answer (score 0):

you also could do the following... however there are easier ways

see jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kasperfish/CR5EX/2/

```
alert('jquery '+$("#section h1").html());

v=document.getElementById("section").getElementsByTagName("h1");

alert('javascript '+v[0].innerHTML);
```