# Why are css selectors interpreted differently by JQuery and Capybara?

Tags: jquery, capybara, capybara-webkit

I'm writing tests for a web app using Capybara. I'm trying find a node in the DOM using the following set of selectors.

```
'[ng-repeat="task in taskList.items"]:last-child .editable-select [multiple="multiple"]'
```

When I pass these selectors to JQuery, via the javascript console in Chrome, they retrieve the correct node.

```
$('[ng-repeat="task in taskList.items"]:last-child .editable-select [multiple="multiple"]')
```

=>

```
[
<select multiple=​"multiple" ng-options=​"s.index as s.path for s in files" class=​"editable-input ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-model=​"$data">​…​</select>​
]
```

When I pass the exact same selectors to Capybara's `find` method, however, I get an Element Not Found exception.

```
find('[ng-repeat="task in taskList.items"]:last-child .editable-select [multiple="multiple"]')
```

=>

```
Capybara::ElementNotFound Exception: Unable to find css "[ng-repeat=\"task in taskList.items\"]:last-child .editable-select [multiple=\"multiple\"]"
```

If the selectors work properly in JQuery, why don't they work in Capybara? How could I rewrite my query to be Capybara-compatible?

Comment: Please accept @Joe's answer if you're not unhappy with it. I personally think it clarifies more than you asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS selectors are handled natively by Capybara. For example, [capybara-webkit](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/blob/master/src/capybara.js#L43) uses [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll). Other drivers will similarly delegate to their browsers' native selector engines.

On the other hand, jQuery uses [Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/), which is a custom selector library. It extends and customizes the set of selectors which are natively available in the browser.

For more information, check out this discussion: [jQuery vs document.querySelectorAll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11503534/jquery-vs-document-queryselectorall)