# What is the difference between Sizzle and document.querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, sizzle, queryselector

For what I know, Sizzle and `querySelector/querySelectorAll` are CSS selectors.
So... What is the difference between loading Sizzle and doing:

```
Sizzle("my CSS query")
```

and

```
document.querySelectorAll("my CSS query")
```

Also, I am aware that Sizzle returns an array of an element while querySelectorAll returns a NodeList (in most browsers). I am also aware that you need to load Sizzle and that you can use `document.querySelector` for only one element.

So is there any *other* difference in performance?

**EDIT**: My question *is only* about the Sizzle selector engine (and `querySelectorAll`). Please do not involve jQuery.

Comment: One is a library, the other built in browser functionality. You've outlined the differences that entails. I'm not sure what else you're looking for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery vs document.querySelectorAll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11503534/jquery-vs-document-queryselectorall)

Comment: @VLAZ If you [take a look at Sizzle](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sizzle@2.3.5/dist/sizzle.js), you'll notice that there is so much code. Sizzle makes use of `querySelector` as well but there is obviously so much more. One can't help but wonder, why?

Comment: @Ma'mounothman It describes about how jQuery has more functions than just `querySelector` in VanillaJS. My question here is about the Sizzle selector engine without jQuery (or any) additions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Sizzle is a pure-JavaScript CSS selector engine designed to be easily
>   dropped in to a host library.

Its a spin-off of jQuery project they say, but when it comes to differnce between jQuery and Sizzle, JQuery is a library build to simplify javascript complex syntax that people found hard to understand and get a grid of specially the begineers. So if you are using JQuery, there is going to be a lot of overhead along with it where as sizzlers offer comparatively less.

Its preferred to use querySelector over Sizzler because its just an added overhead which can very easily be done with VanillaJS so why waste it. They both do the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

`Sizzle` was created at a time when `querySelectorAll` did not exist. And its development was continued after the introduction of `querySelectorAll` to get around browser bugs with the early implementations of `querySelectorAll`.

`Sizzle` itself tries to directly use `querySelectorAll` and will only use its own DOM traversing, if either the selector is not supported or know to be buggy for the given browser version. So, for modern browsers, there shouldn't be a noticeable difference in performance, because `querySelectorAll` would be used in both cases.

Compared to `querySelectorAll`, `Sizzle` allows defining custom pseudo-selectors, with the downside that you then cannot benefit from the performance `querySelectorAll` provides nowadays.

So nowadays and if you don't need custom pseudo-selectors, there is no real need for `Sizzle` anymore. You will only use it if you need to target older browser versions that are known to be buggy.